# How do I switch back and forth between pages without reloading all the content

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a learning app where it shows you the concept, then it gives you a quiz. After the quiz it brings you back to the concept. The problem is once it brings me back to the concept, it reloads the concept page and sets it back to the first concept, when I want it to be at the second concept.
Concept 1-> switch to concept 2 before the quiz->back to concept 1, but I need it to stay at concept 2

Concept code, calling the function index.html

```
<form id='next'  action='q2.html'>
      <button id="nexttwo" name="nexttwo" onclick="next()">Test</button>
        </form>
```

Concept code, function, js

```
function nextc(){

    cpg++ //switches the page number
 
 
    let content=document.getElementById('content')
    let image;
    let title;

switch(cpg) //shows content according to page number
 { 
  case 0:
     content="this works it is the third concept";
     title="reading the perodic table";
     nexttwo.style.display='none';
  next.style.display='none';
      break;
      case 1:
      learn.style.display='none';
      time.style.display='none';
     atomImg= document.querySelector(".example").src="atom1c.png"; 
    
  content.innerHTML="Lorem ipsum"
  
  placeholders=[] 
  break;
  case 2:
  
  nexttwo.style.display = "block";
  
  
    content.innerHTML="lorem ipsum 2"
  
     image=[] 
      
      }
```

quiz code html switching pages back to the index.html

```
<form action='index.html'>
      <button>next</button>
         </form>
```

However, when it switches back to the concept, index.html, it doesn't show the 2nd concept, only goes back to the beginning, how do I fix this?
Thanks

And yes it is linked.

Comment: You could put the quiz content in a div and the concept content in another div. Apply a class to the divs to show/hide them alternately.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it worked. it created a new error though, but less problematic.